# Embed file into specific column and go down one row of the column to insert another file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a catalog where a user will write a description and embed files (pdf, Excel, PowerPoint) into an Excel sheet.

I made the text input from the user go down one row with each entry with: `shj.Range("B" & n + 1)` but this doesn't work with embedding a file.

Here is how the sheet looks [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtSVD.png).

I'm trying to insert the file into cell at column C and go down one row to insert another file.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the description", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim shj As Worksheet
worksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
Set shj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(worksheetName)
Dim n As Long

n = shj.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
shj.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value

Dim FName As String

shj.Range("C" & n + 1).Select '<~ this doesn't seem to work
FName$ = Application.GetOpenFilename

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=FName, _
  Link:=True, _
  DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
  Height:=10).Select

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to work", meaning what?

Comment: Perhaps you can try to change the not-working part to this: cells(n+1,3).select

Comment: Why are you going around in circles with `worksheetName`, just use `Set shj = ActiveSheet`.  Also, I'm not sure what `Application.Rows.Count` returns; I think you want shj.Rows.Count.  Last point (I don't have excel open to test), I'm not sure using `.Select` while a modal form (locked focus) is open on top of the workbook is going to get you too far.  If I were you, I'd figure out what all of the  `.Select` statements are doing for you.  Why do you want to `Select` them?  How does _Selecting_ them fit your end goals.

Comment: @MT32 i tried doing `cells(n+1,3)` as you suggested but the file i'm trying to embed still won't go to that column.

Comment: @Profex i am wasn't sure if i use the `.Select` method correctly, but I intend to make it select the cell that is specified in the range of `.Range("C" & n+1)` and insert the file into that specific cell

Comment: Is it "shj.Range("C" & n + 1).Select '" not working, or the following line?
FName$ = Application.GetOpenFilename? It's kinda weird such simple selection code doesn't work...

Comment: Alright, tell me what's supposed to be the value of "getOpenFilename"? Nowhere in the script I see any line referring the filename

Comment: @MT32 it can run but I am unable to get the file insertion to behave as I already specifed in the `shj.Range("C"&n+1)` the file would still be embedded elsewhere rather than in column C. `FName$ = Application.GetOpenFilename` is working fine. that one is to get input from user of what file they're going to embed.

Comment: @MT32 `getOpenFilename` is a method that displays the standard Open dialog box and gets a file name from the user

Comment: shj.Range("C" & n + 1)  = Application.GetOpenFilename     Have you tried this? This way you could skip the selection entirely

Comment: @MT32 doing that method gave me this result [link](https://i.imgur.com/u79LC04.png) it displayed a file path. which not what i had wanted

Comment: Have you walkthrough your code using F8? What does it say when you reach the error line? Using this way maybe you can find the source of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't getting any error per se, I believe that the code is more or less working, but that you just didn't notice the OLE Objects that you've added.  Bring up the Selection Pane and take a look...

**Click** on the ***Home*** menu, *look* under the ***Editing*** group, **click** the ***Find & Select*** button and then ***Selection Pane...***

You should see a list of all the objects on the right hand side.  I'll bet that there are a bunch there if you saved after testing.  Selecting them from the *Pane*, you might notice that they are all located on the top left of cell ***A1***.

---

Since it's just a case of lost/hidden(not-so-hidden) objects I think the following code will help:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Me.TextBox1.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the description", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim shj As Worksheet
    Set shj = ActiveSheet

    Dim n As Long
    With shj
        n = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value

        Dim FName As String
        FName$ = Application.GetOpenFilename
        Dim OLE As OLEObject
        ' You need to set the Top/Left Position & Height/Width to put it where you want it
        Set OLE = .OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=FName, _
            Link:=True, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
            Top:=.Range("C" & n + 1).Top, _
            Left:=.Range("C" & n + 1).Left, _
            Height:=.Range("C" & n + 1).Height, _
            Width:=.Range("C" & n + 1).Width)
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: i have question. Why is this line is repeated two times `Link:=True, _ DisplayAsIcon:=True, _`